# What does "baselet" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

> FONOPs [Freedom of Navigation Operations] have grown “more regular and
>   strident” under the Trump administration,
>   says Alessio Patalano of King’s College
>   London. America’s European and regional
>   allies are not quite as confrontational.
>   They tend to keep a greater distance from
>   China’s bristling baselets.
>
> — *The Economist* pub 6 October 2018 (link not available)

I came across the phrase "bristling baselets" in the sentence "They tend to keep a greater distance from someone's bristling baselets", but cannot find the meaning in any dictionary. Can anyone give its definition or source? Thanks!

Comment: Context needed.

Comment: added  the context in which it appears

Comment: Is the book about computer games or apps or warfare?

Comment: Could be a misspelling of "bracelets".  Otherwise it's a local term or one that must be inferred from the context.  (Ie, a lot more context is needed.  Where did you see this?  Is it a fiction piece, a news story, or something else?  Is the author a skilled writer and was the piece professionally edited, or is it the sort of thing where misspellings would be common?)

Comment: Why didn't you provide the context that Andrew provided, given that you were obviously quoting from the same article?  Failure to do this has cost you downvotes.

Comment: [Woody Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woody_Island_(South_China_Sea))

Answer (score 3):

*Let* is a productive suffix. The *Economist* has coined the term *baselet* meaning small military base. It's bristling with weapons.

> -let
>   sᴜꜰꜰɪx
>
> 1. (forming nouns) denoting a smaller or lesser kind.
>
>    *‘booklet’
>      ‘starlet’*
>
> — [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/-let)